# angularjs single input filed for both email and mobile number

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, angularjs-validation

In the registration form i have single field for both email and mobile number but it doesn't working properly.

```
<form name="regForm" >
<md-input-container flex md-no-float>
   <input ng-model="vm.form.email" type="text" placeholder="Email or Phone" translate translate-attr-placeholder="REGISTER.EMAIL" name="email or phone" ng-pattern="/^([_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,5}))|\d+$/"  required="true">
   <div ng-messages="regForm.email.$error" ng-show="regForm.email.$touched">
     <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
     <div ng-message="email">Your email address is invalid</div>
   </div>
</md-input-container>
</form>
```

Below code showing schema in model file

### userModel.js

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
   name: String,
   email: {type: String, required: true, select: true},
   password: {type: String, required: true, select: true},
});
```

Comment: ng-show= is duplicated

Comment: actually i am not getting how to do for both in single field. Could you please help me?

Comment: do you mean validating the field for email or phone number?

Answer (score 2):

The field you're trying to reference in `ng-messages` and `ng-show` does not exist (there is no input with `name="email"` within the `regForm`).

For what you are trying to achieve I'd use custom validation logic like [here](http://codepen.io/z00bs/pen/XdBMKq). You might even use a custom validator as described in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).